# Please prove that $(p!+1)$ is a prime, where $p$ is a prime.

Tags: real-analysis

I got Euler's proof for the Question:

Prove that there is no largest prime.

But one of the solutions on internet gives this proof by Archimedes:

[image]

Please help me to understand the proof.

Comment: $p!+1$ need not *actually* be prime... it is merely not divisible by any primes $q<p$. Consider $7!+1=71^2$

Comment: E.g. $5!+1=11^2$.

Comment: This is not in the surviving works of Archimedes. Known and standard much earlier.

Comment: You have fallen into the same trap that misleads vast numbers of beginning students. Please notice that the proof, as quoted, **does not say** that $p!+1$ is a prime, only that it is not divisible by any of the numbers that are $\le p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $p$ is the largest prime.

By the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), you can write $p! + 1$ as a product of primes, which are necessarily not larger than $p$, and thus are factors of $p!$.

But $p! + 1$ divided by any integer $q \le p$ gives remainder $1$, as
$$
p! + 1 = q \cdot (p \cdot \ldots \cdot (q+1) (q-1) \cdot \ldots 2 \cdot 1) + 1,
$$ and so $p! + 1$ is not divisible by $q$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $p!+1\gt p$. By assumption $p$ is the largest prime, so $p!+1$ cannot be prime. Hence it has a prime divisor $q|p!+1$. But $q\le p$, so $q|p!$. From this we conclude $q|p!+1-p!=1$, which is absurd. If the assumption that there is a largest prime leads to a contradiction, then the assumption must be false and there is no largest prime.

Answer (score 1):

This is a proof by contradiction. If you suppose $p$ is the largest prime, then $p! + 1$ being strictly larger than $p$ cannot be prime and hence by Fundamental Theorem of ARithmetic, there is a prime $q$ that divides $p! + 1$ and since $q < p$, $q | p!$ and since it also divides $p! +1$, it divides $1$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

$p! = p(p-1)(p-2)\cdots 1$ which is divisible by $q$ for all $q \leq p$. So if $p! + 1$ is divisible by prime $q$ where $1 < q \leq p$ (which must be true if $p$ is the largest prime because every number has a unique prime factorization), then you can subtract $p!$ from $p! + 1$ and the answer must again be divisible by $q$, but the difference is $1$ and $q > 1$, which gives a contradiction. So there cannot be a largest prime $p$.